# Parsing JSON String Array of Arrays in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to parse json string in spring using pojo classes. I've a json string as:

```
{
 "values": [
                    [
                        1509836400000,
                        670042.375,
                        2
                    ],
                    [
                        1509836400000,
                        670042.375,
                        2
                    ]
         ]
 }
```

Can somebody help me how do I parse this string to object of the form

```
class Value{
   long timeStamp;
   double value;
   int flag;

  // getters and setters
 }

class Values{
    Value[] values;
  // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could try to generate the POJO with : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/, see https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1f5ff6c990dd36eb366c3e82c7b5f92f

Comment: Problem is I have three types. Long, Double and Int :(

Comment: Declare them using the *most common* (double here: I mean 2 can be a double value)

Comment: Thanks. I was doing the same. I wanted something consistent. I will create a wrapper around it. :)

Answer (score 1):

use [Gson](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.6.2/) library to parse Json to Java like this.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Values values = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString , Values.class);
```

you can convert Json to Java POJOs using this tool [Json to Java](http://www.freecodeformat.com/json2pojo.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jackson 2
[Reference](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the jackson library which is able of converting the string object to the desired pojo class

so please check this example

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score 0):

If you are able the change the json to meet your model/pojo
just convert it from array to object like this Json:

```
{
    "values": [ {
         "timeStamp" : 1509836400000,
         "value" : 670042.375,
         "flag" : 2
       }, 
       {
         "timeStamp" : 1509836400000,
         "value" : 670042.375,
         "flag" : 2
       } ]
}
```

If you aren't able to change the json, you can map the values as `List<List<Double>>`, and then get every one by index: 0 for timeStamp and so on. Your model/pojo should be:

```
class Values {
   List<List<Double>> values;
   // getters and setters
}
```